# PayPal - Javascript - REST - Error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to implement PayPals's REST API in my single page app. I can get my token well enough but when I try to POST a dummy payment to my sandbox I get the following error:

```
<ns1:XMLFault xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">
    <ns1:faultstring xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">java.lang.NullPointerException</ns1:faultstring>
</ns1:XMLFault>
```

I've created a [PostMan gist](https://gist.github.com/JDillon522/a58bbf09728d717b65a2) with my requests for both `v1/oauth2/token` and `v1/payments/payment` using my sandbox authorization.

I have no clue what I'm leaving out or doing wrong.

FYI: the authorization for the `payments/payment` route in my gist is set to `Bearer ****` because you need to add in the token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the problem was that I was sending the content type as `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` and it needs to be set to `Content-Type:application/json`.